# How to change the configuration's by using the parametrized build based on the parameter?

Tags: jenkins

```
choice parameter
 Name
    a
    b
    c
```

I have a parametrized build with choice parameters like a,b,c,d. When I select `a` parameter, it has to do fresh checkout, and, when I select `b` it has to update the work space of Jenkins.

Right now whatever the parameter choose either `a,b,c`, it is checkout policy is fresh checkout only.

Can any one let me know how to set different properties based on the selected parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to forego the Jenkins SCM checkout configuration, and maintain the SCM checkout through a script (either **Execute Shell** or **Execute Batch Command**). Your script would then handle the logic of doing a certain type of checkout/update based on passed parameters

**Late edit:**
You could configure a **[Pre-scm Build Step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep)**, and there run either a **[Conditional Build Step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin)** or a plain shell execution (bash or batch). In that shell, test the param, and if it matched `b`, then wipe the local workspace/checkout folder from the shell script.

When the rest of the job runs, it will do a fresh checkout (since the workspace/checkout is empty). With other param options, it will run the job normally, doing an update.

I haven't tried this. Your biggest issue may be if pre-scm build step does not have access to environment variables at that time.

Comment: thanks for the response...is there any possibilities to conquer my goal through the config.xml of Jenkins...if you have any script could you please share?

Comment: If you can't do it in UI, it's likely not possible through config.xml either. Modifying the config.xml is possible, but that require the action to be "pre-build". You are implying an "mid-build" action. You could have multiple jobs, one that does fresh checkout, one that does update, and then have a third job, a wrapper that decides, based on param, which job to trigger

Comment: @napp edited the answer with another possible solution